# How to remove unique rows based on customer name using sql query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table which is as follows:

```
cust_name   cust_address  sex  orderactive
xxxx        yyy            m    1
iiii        iii            f    1
xxxx        yyy            m    1
```

I want to **keep the duplicate entries** and **remove unique one's** and my resultant table (after removing the duplicates) should look like -

```
cust_name   cust_address  sex  orderactive
xxxx        yyy            m    1
xxxx        yyy            m    1
```

Any clues or help would be appreciated.

Comment: its not removing duplicate rows....the question is about removing rows which come only once based on cust_name and not twice.. @nondestructive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following query:

```
SELECT cust_name
FROM mytable
GROUP BY cust_name
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

to get the `cust_name` values of duplicate records.

Use this query as a derived table and join back to the original table to get the desired result:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM mytable AS t1
JOIN (
   SELECT cust_name
   FROM mytable
   GROUP BY cust_name
   HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) AS t2 ON t1.cust_name = t2.cust_name
```

Comment: @Glorgos Besos The above query(second part) is saying cust_name is invalid

Answer (score 0):

You can use group by having :

```
SELECT *
FROM Persons
WHERE cust_name IN
    (SELECT cust_name
     FROM Persons
     GROUP BY cust_name
     HAVING count(cust_name) > 1)
```

[http://sqlfiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c33aed/6/0)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following query to **delete the unique rows** from the table. Unique rows are identified as `HAVING COUNT(cust_name) = 1`.

```
DELETE FROM cust_details 
WHERE cust_name 
IN (
    SELECT cust_name 
    FROM (SELECT * FROM cust_details) AS cust_details_alias 
    GROUP BY cust_name HAVING COUNT(cust_name) = 1
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Use subquery to get the id's of the repeating rows, which then will be used in where condition. Your solution is:

```
select DISTINCT * from tbl as tbl1 
where cust_name IN (
Select cust_name from tbl where 1 < (
Select count(*) from tbl where cust_name = tbl1.cust_name))
```